# Authorize.net credit card payment for non US customers

Tags: payment, authorize.net, payment-processing

I have a website which gives the posibility to our clients to publish some adds on it. The add is first received and checked internaly by an add editor. Then, we are asking the client for the payement and when the payement is received, the add is published.

My goal is to give the possibility to our clients to pay with their credit card. For example, send them the invoice by email with the link (or button) to a webpage where they could introduce their Credit Card number etc.

The company is situated in switzerland and our Bank too.

I am reading actually a lot about the Authorize.net but apparantly, we shuld have a bank in US ? Our clients are based worldwide, can this be a problem and reason for extra fees.

Can we easly send invoices by email with the link for credit card payment?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you ask authorize.net directly instead of posting questions on random sites on the net?

Comment: Befor contacting them, I would like to know if somebady with the similar case as my had an experience with them. And also, may be I will get some other suggestions about other third party merchant. I choosed stackoverflow due to my knowledge of the website, I havemt choose it randomly

Comment: authorize.net is nothing but friendly and willing to answer questions in my previous dealings with them. you really SHOULD go directly to them instead of soliciting the opinion of random people on the net.

Comment: Ok, I will contact them today, but I am still thinking that any opinion could be useful.

Comment: When dealing with credit card processing, opinions are not going to cut it. either you fully comply with PCI and your processor's policies, or you don't get to play at all.

Comment: I agree completly with that, but I thinked about the third party merchand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am reading actually a lot about the Authorize.net but apparantly, we shuld have a bank in US? Our clients are based worldwide, can this be a problem and reason for extra fees.

Authorize.Net is currently only available in the US so you must have a US merchant account to use their services.

> Can we easly send invoices by email with the link for credit card payment?

Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much John, your responses are very helpful.
Ok, so, instead of contacting directly Authorize.net, I have to contact an US merchant provider (some addresses can be found on Authorize.net website) and ask for opening a merchant account. Then, I can use for example the authorize.net PHP library and create my emails etc ? Am I right ?

Comment: Exactly. The only tricky part is getting the US merchant account. It requires having a registered US company or someone with a social security number signing the paperwork as the guarantor. But if you can do that the rest is relatively easy.

Comment: Hm, I don't hawe a registred US company, the company is based is Switzerland

Comment: That's the tricky part. There probably is a way to get a shell company set up in the US but that's not my area of expertise so I can't give you any guidance on this.